# For the equation $x^3 -y^3 + x-y=0$, how many real functions on $-\infty <x < \infty$ does this equation define?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm able to factor the equation $x^3-y^3+x-y=0$ to $(x-y)(x^2 + y^2 + xy + 1)=0$ to  get that the only factor of the equation is $y=x$. But, I'm also told that there is one function, namely $f(x) = x$, that the equation defines. I'm kind of confused about what this is supposed to mean. Are we defining a function such that every $x \in (-\infty, \infty)$ is mapped to $0$ by  $g(x) = x^3-y^3+x-y$?

Comment: Isn't $f(x)=x$ really just same as $y=x$ [i.e. $y-x=0$] in another notation?

Comment: The equation says $x^3 + x = y^3 + y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because for any real numbers $x,y$,
$$x^2+y^2+xy+1\ge \frac{1}{2}[(x+y)^2+x^2+y^2]+1\ge 1,$$
we know that 
$$x^3-y^3+x-y=0\iff x-y=0.$$
Hence, the subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by the equation is exactly the line $y=x$. It is the graph of $f(x)=x$.